# Packing node webkit application

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, serverside-javascript

I'm new to node webkit and I'm confused about the packaging steps. I just compressed the whole files including the webkit files to make package.zip file. I just copied it to another machine and unzipped it. The nw executable file is not executable there. Its not doing anything when I clicked on it. My concern is

- Will the user be able to use the package by just double clicking on the package provided. Or should he need to unzip the package and execute ?
- What are the steps to be followed to package the app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's explained here https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps

There is special tool to make packages: https://github.com/mllrsohn/node-webkit-builder
And here how I do in my project https://github.com/Paxa/postbird/blob/master/Rakefile